# Security using Tastypie in Mobile Devices Best practices

Tags: django, security, api, tastypie

Which is the best way to use Django / Python Tastypie to build and API for mobile devices?

What I want to do is:

- People connection to some api.domain.com/dosomething/
- I would like that people could identify themselves without cookies.
- I want something more or less secure ( I am afraid people could look into the code to find some API_SECRET )

Is tastypie a good option? Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tastypie has built in [api key authentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication), you can exchange username and password pair for a key when user logs in and keep it on the device. You can even allow user to revoke the key if they want to.